# JavaScript Promises - force promise to resolve

Tags: javascript

Considering that I have the following:

```
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve("Failure"), 5000));

const response = await Promise.race([infinite_task, timeoutPromise]);
```

The `infinite_task` is a promise that never resolves or rejects.
I tried to use `Promise.race` but it will never compare both promises, since `infinite_task` never ends.

How can I force `infinite_task` to resolve after a timeout (in this case, after 5 seconds)?

Comment: Are you sure `Promise.race` doesn't work? *"The `Promise.race()` method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise."* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: Do you mean how can I cancel an unsettled promise?

Comment: What do you mean with *"compare both promises"*? Say you would force a promise to resolve, what use will that be for such a comparison -- as you don't have a realistic resolution value for it?

Comment: A promise that never resolves is not a promise - it is a long running process disguised (inappropriately) as a promise.

Comment: Sounds like the `timeoutPromise()` should be housed within a `while()` loop that is terminated when the `timeoutPromise()` resolves/rejects.

Comment: "A promise that never resolves is not a promise" - sure it is. For example consider a web server that spawns a background process that will likely stay alive for the duration of the server. It may error (thus you get a promise for it you can error handle for) and if it does you want to know, clean up and act appropriately (e.g. restart the background process) but it's very rare for it to actually resolve. It's quite a common pattern I've seen in Node code.

Comment: Also the question (and comments) use "resolve" but actually mean "settle" :]

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - yes, settled :-) - A promise that never settles is not a promise then. That is by definition and a bit pedantic, but the statement is accurate. This is from the Promises/A+ "standard": "_A promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation_" - This is from the ECMA spec: "_A Promise is an object that is used as a placeholder for the eventual results_" -- The concept of an eventual result appears everywhere. Thus the foundation of my opinion on the matter. _Can_ they be used as you describe? Clearly - should they? Not IMHO. We can disagree on the matter:-)

Comment: Well, first of all: that section is non-normative. Second of all that section is part of Promises/A+ which is not the standard we use (we use the ECMAScript standard version). Third - the definition of a promise is simply "something of the Promise type" - which `new Promise(() =>{})` clearly is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a behavioural error in the `setTimeout` function. You are passing the result of the `resolve` function (that is `undefined`) as parameter of the `setTimeout`, when you should pass a callback. This means that your `timeoutPromise` actually resolves instantly and not after the real timeout. This behaves as you expect:

```js
let infinite_task = new Promise(() => { /* never resolving promise */ });

const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => { // this is the needed change to the callback
    resolve("Failure")
  }, 5000)  
});

const response = Promise.race([
    infinite_task,
    timeoutPromise
])
.then(e => console.log('Result:', e));

// making it a function
function awaitFor(promise, millis) {
  return Promise.race([
    promise,
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // NOTE: here better to use reject so we can use catch to see if 
        // the promise was fulfilled or timeout was elasped
        setTimeout(() => reject('timeout'), millis)
    })
  ]);
}

awaitFor(infinite_task, 10000)
  .then(() => console.log('infinite task was not so infinite!'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error2:', e));
```

#### Decomposing your code:

For clarity I decompose in steps what you did:

```js
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve("Failure"), 5000));

// Promise function dec.
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve("Failure"), 5000)
});

// setTimeout arguments dec.
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    let timeout = 5000;
    let callback = resolve("Failure") // this fulfill the promise and returns undefined
    setTimeout(callback, timeout);
});

// variable-values substitutions
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve("Failure") // this fulfill the promise and returns undefined
    setTimeout(undefined, 5000); // this pratically do nothing
});

// contraction (actual code executed, at the end of the day)
const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => resolve("Failure"));
```